# Como configurar Appium utilizando Selenium Web Driver (C#) - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, appium

Boa tarde,

Li alguns blogs sobre a configuração do Appium, mas ainda estou meio perdido. Necessito configurar o **Appium** utilizando o **Selenium Web Driver** no **VS (C#)**.

Atualmente trabalho com Eclipse e Selenium Web Driver, mas agora preciso mudar para C# para validar aplicações em C# (Browser´s) e Mobile (IOS e Android).

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Selenium é só para Desktop. Você quer utilizar o Selenium fora do ambiente de um navegador? Se for, é na mesma instância de máquina (tá virtualizado)? Se for isso, precisará configurar o Selenium para iniciar o servidor em uma conexão já existente no localhost para conectar com o emulador do Appium.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar os seguintes posts para atender seu objetivo.

Esse primeiro mostra a configuração do Selenium utilizando C#

http://www.taketest.com.br/2015/12/10/selenium-webdriver-instalacao-configuracao-e-teste-inicial-com-c/

Esse segundo, mostra um exemplo de app utilizando VS e appium

http://www.taketest.com.br/2016/05/19/testes-em-aplicativos-moveis-utilizando-visual-studio-e-appium/